# .txt embed in .asp file

Tags: asp-classic, text-files

I'm new to ASP and having a little trouble.

A CMS is pushing out data into .txt files. I do not have the option to change what the CMS outputs, so they have to be .txt files.

a text file named textfile.txt looks like this:

```
widetxt=<P align='left'><B>Hello world!</B></P>&done=1
```

I need to display the "widetxt" variable on an .asp page.

The directory structure is like this:

ASP file is at the root of a folder, textfile.txt is located in a folder named "txt" off of the root folder.

```
index.asp
[txt]
  |----textfile.txt
```

I tried the below code in the asp file, but I get a 500 error: "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

```
<%
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set wfile = fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("txt/textfile.txt"),1,true))
filecontent = wfile.ReadAll

wfile.close
Set wfile=nothing
Set fs=nothing

response.write(filecontent)
%>
```

I know for a fact both files are on the server and are where they are supposed to be.

If i remove the above code, and just put:

```
<%
response.write("Hello World!")
%>
```

the asp file works. So something in the OpenTextFile code is wrong, but i do not have the experience to know what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused - is this ASP.NET with VB.NET? You've tagged it ASP.NET, mention PHP and your file extension and code samples look a bit like ASP-classic to me.

Comment: In the 4th sentence of your question you stated: 'I need to display the "widetxt" variable on a php page.' Did you mean `asp` page?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was still editing the question. I've corrected it. No PHP, and I didnt know what else to tag it as. As I said I am new to ASP.

    response.write(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_SOFTWARE"))
    
retrurns:
Microsoft-IIS/7.0 

Not sure if that helps

Comment: go to tools->options and turn off display friendly error messages in IE or similiar thing in your browser... that should show you the actual error...

Comment: Friendly messages not on. Same message in chrome, IE, firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set wfile = fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("txt/textfile.txt"),1,true))
```

You have one too many `)` at the end of this statement. Every `(` should have a matching `)`.

```
Set wfile = fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("txt/AttachmentFix.txt"),1,true)
```

Also, I don't see the remainder of your code, but after your `response.write(filecontent)` make sure to set `filecontent` as `Nothing`.

```
Set filecontent = Nothing
```

Also, when you're developing in Classic ASP @jsobo is right - you should have Friendly Error messages disabled as you can see what errors the script is throwing back.

Comment: this sort  of works... the 500 error is gone. 
Now, where the content of the text file should appear, I get two question mark symbols and a "w":

��w

Comment: I saved the text file as a UTF-8 file and that made it display properly.